# Error launching Android Simulator in Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device

I created a very basic android application in C# using `Blank App(Android)` project template. While launching the application to debug I'm getting following error:

> PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define
>   ANDROID_SDK_ROOTEmulator Nexus_5X_API_23 cannot be started.

Complete logs in output window of Visual Studio is as below:

> 1>Starting deploy Nexus_5X_API_23 ... 1>Starting emulator
>   Nexus_5X_API_23 ... 1>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE
>   -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Nexus_5X_API_23 -prop monodroid.avdname=Nexus_5X_API_23 1>PANIC: Cannot find AVD system
>   path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOTEmulator Nexus_5X_API_23 cannot be
>   started. 1>
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I'm running Visual Studio 15 Preview 5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to set these value on visual studio properties.
[image: Visual Studio Xamarin Android Settings]